# Azure portal metrics weird numbers

Tags: azure, azureportal

I'm trying to view our peak bytes received/sec count for an eventhub in order to scale it properly. However, the portal is showing vastly different results from the "daily" view to the "hourly" view.
This is the graph using the "hourly" view:
[image]

From here, it looks like I'm peaking at around 2.5 MB/s. However, if I switch to the "daily" view, the numbers are vastly different:
[image]

So I can't make sense of this. It's the exact same counter, showing vastly different results. Anyone know if the Azure portal performs any "adding" or similar?

Edit: Notice that the counter is "bytes received per second". It shouldn't matter if I look at the hourly or daily view, the number of items per second shouldn't be affected by that (tho it clearly is).

Comment: I guess it is aggregating numbers over larger time periods in the second one? :)

Comment: but the counter is "per second" - no aggregation should be done imho.

Comment: True.. Anyway then it would have to show 60 data points between each minute in the top graph and 3600 in the bottom one.  Which I'm sure they could do, but it might be just saving storage costs :)

Comment: or confusing users trying to scale their services correctly.